# What is 'PreviewProvider' in swiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

Recently I have started implementing `swiftUI`. Wondering what is `PreviewProvider`? how and when it will be called?

Is it the same as `init()`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this https://www.avanderlee.com/xcode/xcode-previews/ and apple official doc : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/previewprovider to know more

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`PreviewProvider` is a protocol used for generating previews that you can see on the right-hand side in Xcode.

[image: Xcode UI]
As you can see in the picture you have this preview, but it is only visible when you are using macOS Catalina. The structure that implements it is called when the preview needs to be generated. It hasn't called when you run your app.

You can read more about this protocol in [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/previewprovider)

Comment: So is this a sort of "Object" viewer that will give you some details about the object for debugging purposes?

Comment: @xTwisteDx Nope, it just generates a preview when developing. Kind of similar to `@IBDesignable` in Interface Builder.

Comment: What I understood, its protocol which Xcode detect statically and will not get called when run the app